# Where do .Net applications derive their root CA certificates?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ssl, certificate

I am trying to use Charles Proxy with a .Net application to understand its API calls. I've installed the Charles Proxy root CA certificate (which is working as expected for base OS services and the browser), however the application I'm running doesn't seem to be recognizing that cert.

I've decompiled the software, and it seems to be using the standard `System.Net.WebRequest` component, and doesn't override `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`.

This is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, .NET uses the Windows certificate trust system; so it should behave the same as Edge or Chrome (Firefox uses their own trust store).

Comment: Interesting. Chrome, Edge, and basic system services are all successfully proxying through Charles, but this particular third-party app is having TLS errors.